# Why Pandas .loc speed in Pandas depends on DataFrame initialization? How to make MultiIndex .loc as fast as possible?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am trying to improve a code performance.
I use Pandas 0.19.2 and Python 3.5.

I just realized that the .loc writing on a whole bunch of values at a time has very different speed depending on dataframe initialization.

Can someone explain why, and tell me what is the best initialization? It would allow me speed up my code.

Here is a toy example. I create 'similar' dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


ncols = 1000
nlines = 1000

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0], [0], np.arange(ncols)])
lines = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0], [0], np.arange(nlines)])

#df has multiindex
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns, index = lines)

#df2 has mono-index, and is initialized a certain way
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = np.arange(ncols), index = np.arange(nlines))
for i in range(ncols):
    df2[i] = i*np.arange(nlines)

#df3 is mono-index and not initialized
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = np.arange(ncols), index = np.arange(nlines))

#df4 is mono-index and initialized another way compared to df2
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns = np.arange(ncols), index = np.arange(nlines))
for i in range(ncols):
    df4[i] = i
```

Then I time them:

```
%timeit df.loc[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0)] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
1 loop, best of 3: 786 ms per loop
The slowest run took 69.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean          that an intermediate result is being cached.

%timeit df2.loc[0] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop

%timeit df3.loc[0] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.4 ms per loop

%timeit df4.loc[0] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.9 ms per loop
```

Have I done anything wrong???? Why is df2 performing so much faster than the others? Actually in multi-index case it is much faster to set the elements one by one using .at. I implemented this solution in my code but I'm not happy about it, I think there must be a better solution. I would prefer to keep my nice multi-index dataframes, but if I really need to go mono-index I'll do it.

```
def mod(df, arr, ncols):
    for j in range(ncols):
        df.at[(0, 0, 0),(0, 0, j)] = arr[j]
    return df

%timeit mod(df, np.arange(ncols), ncols)
The slowest run took 10.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean  that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: In the first example, `df.loc[(0,0,0), (0,0)]` is partial labelling - it drops the upper levels of the multiindex, which takes some extra time. Try `df.loc[(0,0,0)]` instead. Moreover, the results of `timeit` may be unreliable due to caching. I'd try `timeit -n1 -r1`.

Comment: thanks ptrj for the timeit tip, and for the df.loc[(0,0,0)]. It already saves a x10 factor (~50ms instead of ~700ms). Unfortunately, the for loop is still faster (~15ms).

Comment: When I call `%timeit -n1 -r1 mod(df, np.arange(ncols), ncols)` the first time after constructing `df` it takes about 170 ms. Each subsequent execution takes about 20-30 ms. All heavy work is probably done during the first run (the function `mod` modifies df). Anyway, I'd rather profile the whole code, not the indexing alone, to see if the indexing really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference I see here is you have (effectively) initialized df2 & df4 with dtype=int64 but df & df3 with dtype=object.  You could initialize with empty real values like this for df2 & df4:

```
#df has multiindex
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([ncols,nlines]), 
                  columns = columns, index = lines)

#df3 is mono-index and not initialized
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([ncols,nlines]),
                   columns = np.arange(ncols), index = np.arange(nlines))
```

You could also add `dtype=int` to initialize as integers rather reals but that didn't seem to matter as far as speed.

I get a much faster timing than you did for df4 (with no difference in code), so that's a mystery to me.  Anyway, with the above changes to df & df3 the timings are close for df2 to df4, but unfortunately df is still quite slow.

```
%timeit df.loc[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0)] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
1 loop, best of 3: 418 ms per loop

%timeit df2.loc[:,0] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
10000 loops, best of 3: 185 µs per loop

%timeit df3.loc[0] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
10000 loops, best of 3: 116 µs per loop

%timeit df4.loc[:,0] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
10000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop
```

#### Edit to add:

As far your larger problem with the multi-index, I dunno, but 2 thoughts:

1) Expanding on @ptrj's comment, I get a very fast timing for his suggestion (about the same as the simple-index methods):

```
%timeit df.loc[(0, 0, 0) ] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop
```

So I again get a very different timing from you (?).  And FWIW, when you want the whole row with loc/iloc it is recommended to use `:` rather than leaving the column reference blank:

```
timeit df.loc[(0, 0, 0), : ] = 2*np.arange(ncols)
1000 loops, best of 3: 223 µs per loop
```

But as you can see it's a bit slower, so I dunno which way to suggest here.  I guess you should generally do it as recommended by the documentation, but on the other hand this may be an important difference in speed for you.

2) Alternatively, this is rather brute force-ish, but you could just save your index/columns, reset the index/columns to be simple, then set index/columns back to multi.  Although, that's not really any different from just taking `df.values` and I suspect not that convenient for you.

Comment: Thanks! Sure it does not help me have a fast multi-index .loc, but at least now I have to trick to make a mono-indexing .loc fast :). Numpy and fancy indexing would work, but it longer to code and de-bug. I would rather stick to Pandas for that reason, but it is not mandatory. Do you know a way to easily swap from multi- to single-indexing; do all the .loc and then swap back to Mulit-index?

Comment: I added onto the end of my answer, dunno if it will help. I'm really not great with multi-indexes but I'd think someone around here could help (though you may want to simplify/shorten this question and then post as a new queston to better focus on the multi-index setting aspect of it -- since edits of old posts tend not to get much attention here)

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your time and your advices. I'm still not perfectly happy with solutions we found, but in that particular case the .loc is no longer the code bottleneck and that is what matters today.

Comment: @tk. Yeah, I am not all that proud of this answer!  Just figured no one else had answered and it seemed like a good question so I gave it a shot.  But I would re-iterate my previous comment and suggest that if you ask a new question that is shorter and more focused you might get a better answer than mine.