# Faster way of setting values on MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a code that is slow. The code profiling shows that clearly the bottleneck is .loc on my Pandas MultiIndex.

Let's say I initialize it this way:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'], np.arange(10), np.arange(1000)])
index = np.arange(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((len(index), len(columns.values))), index=index, columns=columns)
```

And the .loc is very slow (100ms with timeit)

```
%timeit df.loc[5,('a',[0,1],np.arange(100))] = np.arange(200)
10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop
```

How can I make it faster????
Currently I have found a bad solution that consists in setting the values with a for loop (takes 2 ms), but I am sure there is a better solution.
I would like to stick with Pandas MultiIndex DataFrames, and not single index or Numpy arrays.

It is kind of a dupe of [Why Pandas .loc speed in Pandas depends on DataFrame initialization? How to make MultiIndex .loc as fast as possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773364/why-pandas-loc-speed-in-pandas-depends-on-dataframe-initialization-how-to-make/41775954?noredirect=1#comment70859764_41775954) but I way advised to re-ask a simpler question.

Thanks,
Thierry

#### EDIT

since it seems to interest MaxU, here is my faster for loop

```
def mod(df, array):
    k = 0
    for i in [0,1]:
        for j in np.arange(100):
            df.at[4, ('a',i,j)] = array[k]
            k += 1
    return df

%timeit mod(df, np.arange(200))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a part of ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/348814)? Are you going to use `df.loc[]` in a loop?

Comment: in a for loop I can df.at that is faster on single data (no slice). df.at is not faster than df.loc on the slice setting.

Comment: I was asking about whether you call your current `df.loc[ ..slicers.. ]` solution in a `for ... loop` and whether it can be avoided...

Comment: Nope, I use .at. I edited my question.

Comment: i'm trying to ask whether you call `mod()` function in a loop? ;-)

Comment: ah OK I get it. Yes I do call it, because each row corresponds to different files that I need to parse. So I basiscally do a for loop on the index, parse the files, get values from the parsed file and .loc it into the dataframe. Any better idea? I could cythonize the for loop, but efficiently parsing in Cython is currently beyond my current skills.

Comment: what about the following idea - first collect the data (from different files) in a proper shape and then create a DataFrame in one step?

Comment: yeah it could be possibility, though I'm trying to avoid it. And in anycase I have .loc further in the code, so I would like to know whether there is a faster .loc without the mod trick. There is such a difference between singe index .loc and multi-index .loc that I was thinking I was doing something wrong.